# onCick in React changes all of the classes states in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have creates a side bar in react and I want to change their state to active when clicked on each of them, but when I click on any item all of them suddenly get activated. how to fix this?

```
lass Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false,
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}}>
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavLink key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />}className={this.state.active ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })}>
             اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی جدید
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />}className={this.state.active ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })}>
           داشبورد
          </NavLink>
        </NavSection>
      </NavPanel>

    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Sidebar)
```

Comment: Could you provide full code or an online demo so we can make it a quick fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are referring to the same key in your state for all the Navlinks.
There are many options to fix this, but simply, you can keep different keys for different links in your state.

```
lass Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {
    NavOneActive: false,
    NavTwoActive: false,
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}}>
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavLink key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />}className={this.state.NavOneActive? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ NavOneActive: !this.state.NavOneActive, NavTwoActive: false})}>
             اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی جدید
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />}className={this.state.NavTwoActive? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ NavTwoActive: !this.state.NavTwoActive, NavOneActive: false})}>
           داشبورد
          </NavLink>
        </NavSection>
      </NavPanel>

    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Sidebar)
```

Comment: Thank you, but now how should I make them deactivated once I click on another navlink?

Comment: edited the answer above... please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Because your state is globally reduced to these components. You need to create a wrap component with the state and your component separately from each other.